# change a value depending on javascript's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the label depending on the value of the textbox. I tried the code below, but it doesn't change. I think its because that i didn't put any value on my textbox, so if anyone know the best way to achieve this, tell me. =)

```
function changeval(){
  var x = document.getElementById("sff").value;
  document.getElementById("jffx").innerHTML = x;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#state").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'AL'){
        $("#entity").change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'LP'){
                    $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                    $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                    $("#desc").hide();
            }else ($(this).val() == 'LLC'){
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alLLC").show();
}
<input type="text" id="sff" placeholder="$0.00" value="" onchange="changeval()"/>
<label id="jffx"></label>
```

Comment: looks fine  - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1z11ebqp/1/

Comment: looks at your console to see if there are any errors... looks like your script after the `changeval` function has syntactical errors

Comment: i will try this code again.  -@ArunPJohny

Comment: then it should work fine... see the above fiddle...

Comment: now i know why the jfiddle works... because, the user have to input on the textbox, in my case.. its automatic that when the user choos e in the `select` menu  the value will appear on the text box, as well as in the `jffx` id... @ArunPJohny

Comment: @anna my code is working in your case. check that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the value of text field by javascript so you need to change the label from there also.

```
function changeval(){
  var x = document.getElementById("sff").value;
  document.getElementById("jffx").innerHTML = x;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#state").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'AL'){
        $("#entity").change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'LP'){
                    $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                    $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                    $("#desc").hide();
            }else ($(this).val() == 'LLC'){
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alLLC").show();
            }
            changeval(); //you need to call the function here also.
        });
     }
  });
});
```

Try above code.